# How to make typescript infer types correctly in my case?

Tags: typescript

I have some code like this:

```js
type _Map = {
    a: 1
    b: "2"
}

type Fn = <T extends keyof _Map>(key: T, cb: (value: _Map[T]) => any) => void

let fn!: Fn

const fn_map = {
    a: (v: 1): 1 => 1,
    b: (v: "2"): "2" => "2"
}

;(Object.keys(fn_map) as Array<keyof _Map>).forEach(key => {
    fn(key, fn_map[key]/* ← error here */)
})

const fn_map_2 = {
    a: ["a", (v: 1): 1 => 1] as const,
    b: ["b", (v: "2"): "2" => "2"] as const
}

;(Object.keys(fn_map_2) as Array<keyof _Map>).forEach(k => {
    const [key, cb] = fn_map_2[k]
    fn(key, cb/* ← same error here */)
})

//but we known the `forEach()` will be like this ↓
fn("a", fn_map["a"])
fn("b", fn_map["b"])
```

The error says:

> Argument of type `((v: 1) => 1) | ((v: "2") => "2")` is not assignable to parameter of type `(value: 1 | "2") => 1 | "2"`.
>
> - Type `(v: 1) => 1` is not assignable to type `(value: 1 | "2") => 1 | "2"`.
>
>   - Types of parameters `v` and `value` are incompatible.
>
>     - Type `1 | "2"` is not assignable to type `1`.
>
>       - Type `"2"` is not assignable to type `1`.(2345)

---

**I don't want to use `any` (if there are other ways).**

Comment: Your "`List`" is an `object` (with string keys), not an `array` (with integer keys). Why did you name it "List"?

Comment: Your `const list` does not conform to `type List`, btw.

Comment: @Dai This is just some non-standard naming, which has nothing to do with code logic. I've changed it to a `_Map`.